# Why would I still be getting 'Your version of git is 2.1.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.' from heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I got the error on 1.9.3 so upgraded using homebrew to what by default is 2.1.3 on OSX 10.9.5.

I had previously been using an OSX version I think, so I swapped in the path for the brew install into my `.zshrc` file, and upon double check with `git --version` it confirms 2.1.3, so why is Heroku giving this error?
Is this just a bug on their part?

Comment: 2.1.3 is vulnerable.  2.1.4 is not.

Comment: @AndrewC is correct. 2.1.3 is affected by CVE-2014-9390.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to update homebrew. I just did then upgraded git and got 2.3 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see gist like this one to address that error message regarding [`CVE-2014-9390`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#CVE-2014-9390):

> #### [git update (CVE-2014-9390)](https://gist.github.com/st/5a030558b41cdce3e3c6)

```
# On Mac OS X:

# In case, your git is the "apple" version:
sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-apple
brew install git
brew update && brew upgrade git
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git

# In case, it's already managed by brew:
brew update && brew upgrade git

# To check:
$ git --version
git version 2.2.1
```

The vulnerability was patched in version 2.2.1 of Git, released on 17 December 2014.